# Modifying .htaccess to remedy double question marks URL fault, and redirect to correct url

Tags: .htaccess

Is is possible to modify such a case when the URL itself is wrong. I have an app published which have the hardcoded a "?" at the the api string constant, which resulted in double question marks at some of the instances of the endpoint.

The wrong URLs are:

```
https://app.mywebsite.com/api/sub_categories/0??product_type_id=5&country_id=&price=&search_flag=1&min_price=&max_price=&lang=en&page=1&limit=50
```

```
https://app.mywebsite.com/api/sub_categories/0??product_type_id=6&country_id=&price=&search_flag=1&min_price=&max_price=&lang=en&page=1&limit=50
```

Which is messing up the responses altogether. The correct URL would be:

```
https://app.mywebsite.com/api/sub_categories/0?product_type_id=5&country_id=&price=&search_flag=1&min_price=&max_price=&lang=en&page=1&limit=50
```

(there are six, but all of them are caused by /0??). So would it be possible to manage this via htacess or would we require to publish a new build with this fix.

I already tried this rule:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)??(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2 [NE,R=301,L]
```

But it lead to no effect. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\?([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [NE,R=301,L]


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]


    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    #RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried doesn't have any effect because query string isn't part of match in `%{REQUEST_URI}` . You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` to check  if the URL actually contains double `??` .

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\?([^\s]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this Redirect.

Comment: @dan_13th It should work . Are you sure the rule is placed correctly in your htaccess? It should go just bellow `RewriteEngine on` or above your existing rewrites.

Comment: I have edited my original answer and included the .htaccess file in it. I have put the rule like you stated but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @dan_13th Do you have any other htaccess file in `api` folder?